# Java constructor in detail

Tags: java, constructor

My brother works as a teacher in secondary school, and is grading an exam. He asked the question: "What is the purpose of a constructor?"

So now there were some answers like "The constrcutor creates an object..."

Of course he wanted to see something like "The constructor is called after the object's instanciation and is used to initialize an object's member variables..." (just an example)

The problem is that there is a lot of literature where the authors write that the constructor in Java creates the object, and in general most authors seem to avoid a detailed explanation of the whole process.

I think it works like this:

The class constructor is called as an operand of the new operator, since "the name of the constructor provides the name of the class to instantiate." (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

But before executing this constructor the new operator instantiates the class (allocates memory etc.) and sets the member variables to their default values.

Then the constructor is executed and initializes member variables for example.

In the last step the new operator returns a reference to the object.

But I really don't know if this is actually right, and if things happen in the exact order.

Does anyone know about object creation in detail? How does it work if you create a subclass? Is the superclass created first, its constructor called next, then the subclass merged into the existing construct somehow, and its constructor called then? Could someone somehow argue that a constructor "CREATES" an object?

I am really looking forward to reading your answers!

Comment: straight from the docs -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html   and this is also helpful -- http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html

Comment: If you're asking what's our opinion on what your brother should consider correct, it may be more fitting to put it in Programmers (of Stack Exchange).

Comment: Yes Theodoros, you are right, basically I was wondering about your opinions, and of course I hope that someone really knows about the technical details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gory details are covered in the [Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), here is the basics that you need to know on an every day level (continues in the next section, I pointed you at the class initialization which happens the first time a class has new called on it (there are other ways for it to happen too)).

new allocates the memory for the object and initializes it to 0, null, false (depending on the type).  That is why all the instance variables are guaranteed to have initial values.

Assuming new succeeds the constructor is called to allow the programmer to perform other initialization/tasks.

The first thing that a constructor does is call the parent constructor (super(...)).  That happens all the way up the hierarchy until it reaches java.lang.Object which has no parent.

Before the constructor is executed any instance initialization blocks are run, followed by any instance variables that have assignment operators.

There is a special case if an instance variable is marked as final and has an assignment operator which seems to happen before the call to super if I remember right (there is some trick to it).

All of this is why you should never refer to this.method() (implicitly or explicitly) or pass this out of the constructor because you will be making use of an unfinished object.

Comment: *"Never"* use a method in the constructor is an exaggeration. You may have `private` methods that initialize parts of the object to be called conditionally by overloaded constructors. (There are definitely other use cases too, applicable of course only if you *really* know what you're doing.)

Comment: And when the private method is changed later on to call an overridden method you are screwed (potentially).  So, yes, if you expect that your code is going to change over time it is safest to never call one of your own methods in a constructor.  The correct statement is to never call, directly or indirectly, your own overrideable methods from a constructor.  But that isn't as safe as saying never call your own methods from a constructor.

Comment: The Link to the Java Language Spec was really helpful, 12.5 explains it in detail.

Comment: There's so much stuff online like here for example "http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_java_constructor" ...thats just wrong then, but I can understand that some of my brother's students are confused :p

Comment: @TofuBeer I don't think you can override a `private` method. Of course, if you find yourself making your previously `private` methods `public`, especially without checking their call spots, that's another problem entirely (and a big one, admittedly).

Comment: You cannot override  aprivate method, but a private method can call an non-private method.  If that no-private method is overridden by a sublcass then the subclass method will be called which may use uninitalized data.  You may not call the overrideable method in the private method, but someone 5 years later could.  It is something to be aware of.

Comment: Yes, much code online (and in beginner books) muddles the new and constructor and initialization into one blob.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is correct, as far as I know.
The main idea behind constructors is that you can enforce valid states for an object.

Consider a class called "Rational" with two properties: numerator (int) and denominator (int)
The code would look like this (I've omitted the getters and setters for brevity)

```
public class Rational {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Rational(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public double getRationalValue() {
        return (double) numerator / denominator;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rational oneFourth = new Rational(1, 4);
        System.out.println(oneFourth.getRationalValue());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've written a constructor that "demands" values for the numerator and denominator. If you only had a default constructor, anyone could make instances of Rational without specifying a numerator or denominator, and if you don't specify a value for an int variable, they are initialized at zero. And everyone knows the universe collapses if you divide by zero, so we'd like to avoid that.

Anyway, constructors don't make the object, as you correctly explained. You should see them more as a method that is called "post construction".

When it comes to base classes, the constructor of the base class is always called first. This ensures that you can access protected properties of the base class in your subclass constructor.
Since every class in Java inherits from Object, the Object constructor is always called first.

The following snippet:

```
public class Base {
    protected String baseProperty;

    public Base() {
        System.out.println("In base constructor");
        this.baseProperty = "This gets initialized first";
    }

    static class Sub extends Base {
        private String subProperty;

        Sub() {
            System.out.println("In sub constructor, baseProperty = " + baseProperty);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Base base = new Sub();
    }
}
```

prints:

> In base constructor
>
> In sub constructor, baseProperty = This gets initialized first

Answer (score 0):

Right from the specification to clear your doubt about the new and constructor role:

**Creating Objects**

As you know, a class provides the blueprint for objects; you create an object from a class. Each of the following statements taken from the CreateObjectDemo program creates an object and assigns it to a variable:

```
Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
```

The first line creates an object of the Point class, and the second and third lines each create an object of the Rectangle class.

Each of these statements has three parts (discussed in detail below):

**Declaration**: The code set in bold are all variable declarations that associate a variable name with an object type.

**Instantiation**: The new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.

**Initialization**: The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object.